# jQuery where to put dom interaction

Tags: jquery, dom

i´ve already read many questions on stack overflow, but i got no answer to my question.

Im working on a big website with many javascript interaction. In the end i want 1 file with all the code merged. The problem is where i should put code like this

```
$('#changeMailForm').submit(/*some code here*/) // or
$('#loginForm').submit()
```

The loginform is on every page except the user is logged in. so if the user is logged in
the js code is in the file and it tries to bind the submit event. the structure of my js application is:

```
(function(init){
    init(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function($, window, document) {

    $(function() {

        //dom ready

    });

    // Classes, etc.

}));
```

should i write down each event and dont care if its not in the dom or should i check if its there or something completly different? Whats the best practise to keep the application scaleable and reusable.

Comment: For the simple sake of good practice and not calling redundant code, it would make sense to check if the forms exist first (`if ($("#formID").length > 0) ...`)  That also covers the possibility that in future versions of jQuery they may make changes which would break your code if you try to add a handler to an element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in and the form does not exist, the jQuery will not be able to find the selector to bind to. Granted this will effect performance ever so slighty, but you can get away with it.

Alternatively, you could go about creating a PHP JS file which will allow you to print out JS according to the page you are viewing. Something like javascript.js.php?page=home with php code similar to:

```
<?php
if($_GET['page'] == 'home'){
 print "$('#changeMailForm').submit(/*some code here*/) \/\/ or";
 print "$('#loginForm').submit()";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to handle elements that doesn't exist in the page. If a selector doesn't find any elements you get an empty jQuery object back, and applying methods to an empty jQuery object silently does nothing.

However, if you have a lot of different event handlers in different pages, it's more maintainable if you only bind those that you actally expect in each page. That makes the code more maintainable, because you can add elements in a page without having to check the list of all event handlers in the site for conflicts.